# Apache rewrite to subdirectory with exceptions

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

Apache 2.4, I need to create the following rule and place it in my vhosts file :

1. Serve all requests from a certain dns from files in a specific dir
   (examples, requesting "http://www.mydns.com/login.php" should serve the file from subdir "www/subdir/login.php". requesting "http://www.mydns.com/a/b/c/some.php" should serve the file from subdir "www/subdir/a/b/c/some.php")
2. Ignore this rule for some directories (requesting "http://www.mydns.com/cache/myjs.js" should serve normally from "www/cache/")
3. If the request contains the subdir , ignore the rule (requesting "http://www.mydns.com/subdir/login.php" serves normally)
4. Apply the rule to any port/protocol (http, https, other ports like 8080)
5. URL's should not change/redirect on the users browser

I've been trying to use rewrite rules inside a vhost file (one file for each dns) but been having a very hard time with it.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

**Update**

@spacepickle , thanks for the reply. Still no go, I may have not given all the needed details so here it goes.
I will post my conf file and the tests right below.

conf file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.domain.com
    ServerAlias my2.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /etc/www

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/subdir/ - [PT,L]
    RewriteRule ^/cache/ - [PT,L]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /subdir/$1 [PT,L]   
</VirtualHost>
```

GET http://my.domain.com .
expected rewrite http://my.domain.com/subdir .
got fcgi error : The requested URL /subdir/php5.fcgi/subdir/index.php was not found on this server.

GET http://my.domain.com/subdir .
expected nothing happening (ignore rewrite) .
got rewrite : The requested URL /subdir/subdir was not found on this server.

GET http://my.domain.com/cache .
expected nothing happening (ignore rewrite) .
got rewrite  : The requested URL /subdir/cache was not found on this server.

One test case worked : 
GET http://my.domain.com/clients/tests/index.html .
expected and got rewrite to : http://my.domain.com/subdir/clients/tests/index.html

Comment: updated answer with `RewriteRule ^/subdir(/.*)? - [PT,L]` and `RewriteRule ^/cache(/.*)? - [PT,L]` - try again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** Sometimes its best to just stay away from mod_rewrite. My original answer below used mod_rewrite but heres a cleaner solution using mod_alias, which i think addresses the specific use case of the OP. The mod_rewrite solution would become ever more complex, whereas using mod_alias should stay simple (hopefully).

create a base-alias.inc file

```
Alias "/subdir" "${DocumentRoot}/subdir"
Alias "/cache" "${DocumentRoot}/cache"
Alias "/" "${DocumentRoot}/subdir/"
```

Then include this in each virtualhost definition like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  Define DocumentRoot /var/www/www
  DocumentRoot ${DocumentRoot}

  Include base-alias.inc

</VirtualHost>
```

The important line to note here is the `Define DocumentRoot /var/www/www`: this allows you to pass the base directory into your included files.

This should work well with php, and when redirects are issued by modules of apache, since unlike the mod_rewrite strategy further down, the url you are accessing is what the server thinks is the canonical url for the resource.

**Original Answer using mod_rewrite**

Add the following four lines to a file (base-rewrite.inc):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/subdir(/.*)? - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^/cache(/.*)? - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /subdir/$1 [PT,L]
```

**EDIT** added `(/.*)?` to the end of the first two urls to mean, for instance, that only subdir as a folder (with or without slash) or below is part of the first rule. This prevents something like /subdirbutnot/hello being matched

Then include this from your virtualhosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www/

    Include base-rewrite.inc
</VirtualHost>
```

Or add `ServerAlias` lines to use more names:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias new.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www/

    Include base-rewrite.inc
</VirtualHost>
```

Add more virtualhosts with different Document roots, if needed

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName other.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/other/

    Include base-rewrite.inc
</VirtualHost>
```

Or more ports/protocols

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

    Include base-rewrite.inc
</VirtualHost>
```

**An alternative but dubious solution**

Note, the folder path can be dynamically decided by the hostname that was requested, within one virtualhost, but this evaluates environment variables in the path and this is a definite path to a security flaw. Im only showing this as a demo of the flexibility on offer:

base-rewrite-02.inc

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond "%{ENV:ENV_HOST}" ""
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "!^(www|other)\.example\.com$"
RewriteRule ^/(.*) - [E=ENV_HOST:www]

RewriteCond "%{ENV:ENV_HOST}" ""
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "^(www|other)\.example\.com$"
RewriteRule ^/(.*) - [E=ENV_HOST:%1]

RewriteRule ^/subdir/(.*) /%{ENV:ENV_HOST}/subdir/$1 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^/cache/(.*) /%{ENV:ENV_HOST}/cache/$1 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /%{ENV:ENV_HOST}/subdir/$1 [PT,L]
```

And the virtualhost definition:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias other.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/

    Include base-rewrite-02.inc
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thanks, I updated the original post with my testing of your solution

Comment: @RudiBR I should have remembered to include `(/.*)?` on the end of the match rules :)

Comment: tried again with that modification, I understand it's needed anyway, but the test results are the same.

Comment: @RudiBR check you have restarted Apache. It should have at least changed the test result for /cache

Comment: Yes the cache test is working now, with html files at least.
However, if I request a php file, the fastcgi gets messed up like the first test "The requested URL /subdir/php5.fcgi/cache/index.php was not found on this server."

This is turning out to be more a fastcgi issue then a rewrite one.

Comment: @RudiBR if you add your fcgi config to the question and I'll have a look

Comment: @RudiBR i suspect all you need, if it works the way i think it does, is another rule above the first subdir one that says `RewriteRule /php5.fcgi - [PT,L]`

Comment: there is a case which I had not antecipated.
If the user requests a directory (without a slash at the end), the rewrite is working but it's replacing the url in the browser.
For example, calling my.domain.com/clients is serving my.domain.com/subdir/clients as it should, but it is showing this new URL in the browser.
If I request my.domain.com/clients/ with the slash, then it works normally.

Is this an easy fix?

Comment: fyi the RewriteRule /php5.fcgi worked ! If theres no way around the directory issue I posted above, we can live with it too.

Comment: @RudiBR Thanks. I was still thinking about this and just didnt have time to create the solution and test it. Ive updated the answer with a cleaner mod_alias solution that should work better. Let me know if it works for you?

Comment: Hi picke, I've tried the alias solution but am getting fcgi error on any request : The requested URL /php5.fcgi/index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142126/discussion-between-spacepickle-and-rudibr).